# Clearing cookies in office add-in desktop version

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins, word-addins, word-web-addins

I am creating a MS word add-in using office.js library and react. I have implemented login using third party authentication. I am showing login pop up using displayDialogAsync with displayInFrame:False.
I knew that embedded browser for word add-in in my environment is MS edge. I need to manually clear the cookies of third party authentication site but I didn't find the cookies information in MS edge devtools.

I tried to find required cookies info in Microsoft edge browser -> settings -> cookies and site performance -> manage and delete cookies and site data -> see all cookies and site data. But the third party authentication cookies are not available there.

Can anyone please help me to figure out how I can clear third party authentication site cookies for office word add-in embedded browser.

Note: I can find and clear the third party cookies from MS edge settings if I run load the add-in in office word web version.

Comment: Why do you say this: "I need to manually clear the cookies of third party authentication site"? Also, could you explain step-by-step how you do it in Word on the web? At what step do things go wrong in Word desktop?

Comment: There is some error in underline third party authentication system and I am not able to logout. So as workaround, I want to clear third party authentication application cookies. So that access token can be deleted and I will not get auto logged in.
I can clear third party access tokens( by clearing cookies) by following steps in MS edge browser :
Go to settings -> Cookies and Site permissions -> Manage and delete cookies and site data -> see all cookies and site data -> search for site to clear the cookies (ex. login.thidrpartydomain.com) and delete the cookie

Comment: The embedded browser is also Edge. So that same procedure should work for Word desktop. What makes you think it is not working?

Comment: I was also having the same impression that since embedded browser is also Edge, I should be able to clear third party authentication cookies following above procedure. But third party cookies are not available in 'see all cookies and site data' list.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to get some information internally. With the latest Edge webview controll, WebView2, cookies are not shared with the browser, so that is why they don't show up in "see all cookies and site data". There is no UI for clearing the cookies in add-ins. You have to close all Office applications (not just Word) and then delete the folder: “[%AppData%]\Local\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\webview2”